# How do I append items to an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have 5000 log entries in my database and at a time I only load 50 and I have a "Load More" button which should then load 51-100, 101-150 i.e in batches in 50 records.

As I read this cannot be done via Observable. So I am trying to use Subject and I have infact solved the issue but I don't know if it's the right way since I am very new in RxJS and would appreciate your guidelines

Here is my component:

```
export class ControllerLogComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() controller: Controller;
    logEntries: Log[] = [];
    loadMoreCount: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    allLogEntries: Subject<Log[]> = new Subject<Log[]>();
    skip: number = 0;
    max: number = 50; //temp

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private controllerService: ControllerService, private _toast: NotificationsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.controllerService.getLog(this.controller.remoteID, this.skip, this.max).subscribe(a => {
            this.logEntries = this.logEntries.concat(a);
            this.allLogEntries.next(this.logEntries);
            this.loadMoreCount.next(a.length);            
        });
    }

    public loadMore() {
        this.skip += this.max;
        this.controllerService.getLog(this.controller.remoteID, this.skip, this.max).subscribe(a => {
            this.logEntries = this.logEntries.concat(a);
            this.loadMoreCount.next(a.length);
            this.allLogEntries.next(this.logEntries);
        });
    }

      private handleError(error: any) {
        console.log("error: " + error);

    }

}
```

Here is my component html which uses for loop on Subject:

```
<tbody *ngIf="allLogEntries">
            <tr *ngFor="let log of allLogEntries | async">
                <td>
                    <i class="fa fa-toggle-off" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="log.type==0"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="log.type==1"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="log.type==2"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="log.type==3"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="log.type>3"></i>

                </td>
                <td>{{ log.logged | date:'medium' }}</td>
                <td>{{ log.logentry }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Isn't it unnecessarily complicated to use a Subject when you can just iterate the `this.logEntries` where you're appending the results?

Comment: But that is a simple array. How will that be reflected in the view when the items inside that array changes? Don't need something like Observable / Subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to store some sort of state inside an observable stream, you can use `scan()`. For example:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.getElementById('more'), 'click')
  .map(() => [1,2,3])
  .scan((list, items) => list.concat(items), [])
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
<button id="more">load more</button>
```